# swift: Cannot convert value of type to expected element type

Tags: arrays, swift

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with simple example?  "toArray" returns an array ([Float32]) but I get an error in function "THIS_DOESNT_WORK"

**Cannot convert value of type '[Float32]' (aka 'Array') to expected element type 'Float32' (aka 'Float')**

"toArray" clearly return [Float32].  Perhaps its a bug in Xcode?

```
public static func THIS_DOESNT_WORK(data:Data) -> Array<Float32>
{
   return [Test .toArray(data: data, type: Float32.self)]
}
    
private static func toArray<T>(data:Data, type: T.Type) -> [T] where T: AdditiveArithmetic {
      var array = [T](repeating: T.zero, count: data.count / MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
      _ = array.withUnsafeMutableBytes { data.copyBytes(to: $0) }
      return array
}
```

Comment: Remove the `[` and `]` around the `Test.toArray` call. Typo?

Comment: @Sweeper, I'm an idiot.  I'm so used to objective-c syntax, I didn't see that!!